# Create dataframe column by mapping against a dictionary that contains a subset of string value in another column. as its key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary stores that contains name of outlets as keys and the kind of outlet as its value

```
stores = {'McDonalds':'Fast food','African and Eastern Beverage':'Alcohol','Baskin Robbins': 'ice Cream'}
```

I have a pandas dataframe that contains the name of the outlet along with the branch location(in the Merchant Column), some of which have NaN values for the MerchantType

I need to populate the MerchantType column of those rows that have the NaN values and match the merchant type using the stores dictionary keeping in mind that the stores dictionary does not contain the Location (Abu Dhabi, Dubai, Washington, etc.) in the keys.

```
print (df)    
                                     Merchant MerchantType
index                                                     
0                         McDonalds Abu Dhabi          NaN
1                               Dunkin Donuts       Sweets
2          African and Eastern Beverage Dubai          NaN
3                                 Burger King    Fast Food
4      African and Eastern Beverage Abu Dhabi          NaN
5                                 Burger King    Fast Food
6                   Baskin Robbins Washington          NaN
```

What is the most efficient way in getting this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop in dictionary and set only matched values by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and missing values in `MerchantType` column:

```
mask = df['MerchantType'].isnull()
for k, v in stores.items():
    df.loc[df['Merchant'].str.contains(k, regex=False) & mask, 'MerchantType'] = v

print (df)
                                     Merchant MerchantType
index                                                     
0                         McDonalds Abu Dhabi    Fast food
1                               Dunkin Donuts       Sweets
2          African and Eastern Beverage Dubai      Alcohol
3                                 Burger King    Fast Food
4      African and Eastern Beverage Abu Dhabi      Alcohol
5                                 Burger King    Fast Food
6                   Baskin Robbins Washington    ice Cream
```